# Search array members in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, kibana-5

I am new to elastic search.
I have multiple json's as follows..
How to find all the person objects who has carsowned either as CAR A or CAR B

{
personname: A
carsowned :[CAR1,CAR A]
}

{
personname: B
carsowned :[CAR2,CAR B]
}

{
personname: C
carsowned :[CAR3,CAR C]
}

Now the elastic query must return persons who has atleast one car owned as either CAR A or CAR B

So result must be both person A and person B because personA has CAR A,and personB has CAR2...hence the results..

Even the search string to be give in kibana also would be helpful

Comment: have you tried something and it's not working?

Comment: @BudaGavril..Tried in this way {
    "query" : {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : { 
                    "carsowned" : ["CAR A","CAR B"]
                }
           }
        }
    }

Comment: @BudaGavril..Is there anyting wrong with this query?

Comment: is it really a json you indexed?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "carsowned": "CAR1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "carsowned": "CAR2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```